# click listener in Kotlin coroutines using flow replacing RxJava

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I am currently using rxjava, rx binding for button click events, I want to change that to use kotlin coroutines Flow.

how can I convert this bellow code to use Flow please

```
   @Override
    public Observable<Void> getStartFuellingObservable() {
        return RxView.clicks(dataViewHolder.btnStartFuelling);
    }
```

Thanks
R

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/Kotlin-Android-Open-Source/MVI-Coroutines-Flow/blob/master/core-ui/src/main/java/com/hoc/flowmvi/core_ui/FlowBinding.kt#L57

```kotlin
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@CheckResult
fun View.clicks(): Flow<View> {
  return callbackFlow {
    setOnClickListener { safeOffer(it) }
    awaitClose { setOnClickListener(null) }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can build a simple Kotlin Extension Function like the following:

```kotlin
fun View.clicks(): Flow<Unit> = callbackFlow {
    val listener = View.OnClickListener {
        offer(Unit)
    }
    setOnClickListener(listener)
    awaitClose { setOnClickListener(null) }
}
```

[This article is the source](https://ychescale9.medium.com/binding-android-ui-with-kotlin-flow-491c054cdb60)

It contains more info on how to have a similar API to `RxJava` and it's UI bindings. I think you could benefit from a read there